# Inserting data into sql server table through c#

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to do a registration method,and i got it to work before,then i proceded with the rest of the program,and then i came back to this to add something,and it wasn't working anymore,and i can't figure it out,can anyone help me?

```
public void register(string name,string mail,string pass)
{
    using (SqlConnection c = new SqlConnection())
    {
        c.ConnectionString =  System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["conn"].ConnectionString;
        c.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO UserSignInInfo (Username,Email,Password) VALUES (@name,@mail,@pass)", c))
        {
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", name);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@mail", mail);
            command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", pass);
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Edit:the exception im getting is :'An unhandled exception of type 'System.ServiceModel.FaultException' occurred in mscorlib.dll'

Connection String :server=DESKTOP-8VH7V7J;initial catalog=Db;persist security info=True;Integrated Security=SSPI;

This is not ASP.net, this is winforms
This is what i had when it worked,that's what's cconfusing me @MethodMan

The (Name,Email,Password) datatype are all nvarchar

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: Can you show your ConnectionString?

Comment: ok ,made it a comment. Not a good idea. There is a dot net membership system which works very well, is heavily tested and secure. Implementing your own version will lead to disaster especially if you don't pay attention to what you are doing. For example, you insert the password in clear which is a big no no.

The membership and roles provider are there for a reason, use them.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731049(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: OP never said this is an [tag:asp.net] app. It could be a [tag:winforms] app.

Comment: Side note: If you insist on using `AddWithValue` you should also specify the `SqlDbType`. This can be chained in your call as `AddWithValue` implementation returns the created `SqlParamater` instance.

Comment: @Woody, what did you have before you added what you have posted..? can you confirm that you have debugged the code also show the value of what `c` is less the password also wrap the `command.ExecuteNonQuery` around a `try{}catch` and tell us what the exception is if there is one .

Comment: You can use membership providers with winforms... there is also no problem implementing your own providers.  But it is recommended to actually hash+salt the passwords.

Comment: Without an Exception message, this whole question is a waste of everyone's time.

Comment: What really makes any question a waste of time is when the OP doesn't follow its own question and disappears without giving any answer to the request of clarifications. Well he is a newbie so is somewhat forgiven this time but,,,

Comment: Sorry guys,as someone stated,im a newbie,not only in stackoverflow,but also in programming, im going to edit the original post with the info you guys asked for,thank you all for the answers

Answer (score 0):

Check your Username,Email,Password columns Datatypes and sizes in your database(i.e your UserSignInInfo table).May be your inserted data is more than your column data size.